# OpenSSL Hmac and BouncyCastle Hmac Differ

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, hmac, sha256

I am trying to figure out why an hmac in openssl is not giving me the same result as an hmac in java.

in open ssl

```
echo -n "Hello" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac 04d6b077d60e323711b37813b3a68a71
```

Output:
cc598d8840fe409d5fcc1c1c856f9e8c311d1c458850615555857b023f1cd94c

In java

```
String key = "04d6b077d60e323711b37813b3a68a71"
SecretKeySpec key2 = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode(key), "RAW");
String data = "Hello";
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("Hmac-SHA256", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
hmac.init(key2)
byte[] bytes = hmac.doFinal(data.getBytes());
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(bytes));
```

Output:
877f9c8eb44c20987e3978928fbfcea0f1cf99c88f9db904596921b7ecf0613b

I am at a loss why these are different.

Comment: FWIW I got the `cc59...` value (same as OpenSSL) using the Python code `hmac.new('04d6b077d60e323711b37813b3a68a71', 'Hello', hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`, so I suspect your Java code is somehow erroneous.

Comment: Your key is 32 characters, which is 16 bytes after the hex decoding in Java. I believe the key is too small for the SHA256 HMAC. You might just try `key.getBytes()` in Java.

Comment: Oleg nailed it—my Python test also treated the key as a series of ASCII characters.  Using `'\x04\xd6...'` instead of `04d6...` gave the `877f...` result that Java gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSSL treats `-hmac key` option as if the key is just an array of bytes represented as corresponding ASCII characters. The key is thus limited to contain only printable characters.

You can get the same results in Java as in OpenSSL by using

```
SecretKeySpec key2 = new SecretKeySpec( key.getBytes("ASCII"), "RAW" );
```

Alternatively you can use `openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:string` where `string` will be treated as a HEX encoded key.

Comment: I ended up figuring out that the -hmac key was just treating the key as a string, and taking the bytes of that. The version of openssl (0.9.8e) i use doesn't seem to recognize openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt as a command